# Flip Box Animation Works For All Browsers Except Safari and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, safari, css-animations

Safari issues: it is getting cut in half and flipping.
IE issues: It flips and still shows the mirror image of the front of the card and not the back.

I copied code from this blog: https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Works for his site but not mine.

```css
/******
    FLIP BOXES
    ********/
    .flip-container {
      -webkit-perspective: 1000;
      -moz-perspective: 1000;
      -o-perspective: 1000;
      perspective: 1000;
    }

 .flip-container:hover .flipper,  
    .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

    .flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
    }

    .flipper {
 -webkit-transition: 1.0s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

 -moz-transition: 1.0s;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  
     -o-transition: 0.6s;
 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

 transition: 1.0s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;

 position: relative;
    }

    .front, .back {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;

 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
    }

    .front{
 background: url(http://www.../wp-content/uploads/pic.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
 z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .front h2.flipbox-heading {
    position:relative;
    top:40%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#fff;
    }

    .back {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 transform: rotateY(180deg);

 background: #2a3386;
    }



    .back-title {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
    }
    .back-description p{
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
 top: 80px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
    color:#000;
    }
    .back a {
     position:relative;
     top:180px;
     text-align:center;
  
    }
    .back a button:hover {cursor:pointer;}

    .front::before {
 content:"";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(42,51,134, .3);    
    }
```

```html
    <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front col-01">
    <h2 class="flipbox-heading">Networking</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
    <div class="back-title">Networking</div>
    <div class="back-description">

    <p>Most effective manufacturer/distributor networking opportunities in industry</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#Learn More"><button class="flip-button">Button Text</button></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by adding in the extra css needed and cleaning up some of the divs that I used.

Comment: You probably want to add some code. As written right now this is rather a comment, not an answer.

Comment: As @GhostCat has said, this is not an answer. Please provide the code that resolved this for you.